# SQL insert statement

Tags: sql

I want to do the following:

I have a table called Name which has an ID field.

I have another blank table called Transcript

I want to take the ID#s from Name and insert them into Transcript where they do not exist.

Secondly I want to create 10 records with a different COURSE# value in the Transcript table.

Therefore for each Name.ID I would like 10 records in Transcript.ID with a different value under course # ie; 101,201,301

Comment: What's driving these additional 10 records? Is this fact of 10 records coming from a third table called "Course" or something like that? Or is it just "insert 10 records because that's what I want/was told to do"?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
INSERT INTO TableB

SELECT TableA.id FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableB.id IS null
```

Answer (score 0):

Another query that will return the same thing

`INSERT INTO TABLEB
SELECT TableA.ID FROm TableA WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TableB)`

Comment: Most likely, but I wanted to show that there is more than one solution :) .
I did up vote you by the way :p

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting your course numbers from some outside courses table, here is the t-sql:

```
INSERT INTO transcript (name_id, course_id)
SELECT n.name_id, c.course_id
FROM name n 
CROSS APPLY courses c
WHERE n.last_name = 'xxx'
```

This will insert all of the courses in the table for all of the names found by the where clause.